# Find out data protection class for specific files in iOS

Tags: iphone, class, backup, extract, data-protection

I am currently trying to find out which data protection class is used by a particular app.

My first approach was to use an unencrypted iTunes backup to determine the used protection class. I have used [this](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-dataprotection/) to extract the backup. But now I am gonna stuck.

Furthermore, I am not quite sure if the protection class information is available in the iTunes backup file. Considering that Apple can restore an iPhone/iPad from this backup I think these information must be available. Otherwise the OS would not know after a restore how to protect particular files.

So does anyone have an idea or hint on this? Any experiences?
I would prefer a solution that uses the backup file instead of parsing the device's filesystem. Additionally, it would be great to achieve this without jail-breaking the device.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/ciso/ios-dataprotection was mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245001/how-does-ios-data-protection-work/15545252) question. Seems that it'll suit.

Comment: Great tool! ;-) (I developed this a year ago after I haven't got an answer here... ;-)

Comment: Yep. So, thanks for great tool(and relevant references too). :)