# iOS: Complete Data Protection when device is unlocked

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I have watched Apple's security video [about protecting user's data](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/#714) and also read about Complete Data protection:
Here on SO someone had a similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245001/how-does-ios-data-protection-work) without any solution.

Complete Data Protection makes sure that the users data can't be accessed on the file system, if the device is locked. (granted its password protected).

Apple claims its as easy as doing the following and it would be taken care of automatically.

[image]

Maybe things have changed since last year, but I have setup the complete data protection in the provisioning profile. Set the project to the new provisioning profile and enabled Data protection:

[image]

I have built it and redployed on the iPhone.  However even in locked mode, I still can go via iExplore and access my application's sqllite db.

What am I missing please? Do I have to add this entitlement manually to the project or has it been taken care of when turning it on? (see above)

Comment: did you manage to fix the problem? I am having a similar issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find a solution. I kept the `Data Protection` enabled for the sake of it. But my tests show it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your device is not enabled as **a developer device** in XCode organizer.

Change the developer mode and reset your device after that. I would recommend to hold power and home button until the apple logo appears.

After that when the device is locked and you can try to extract the file from iExplorer the file the operation should fail silently (you won't get an error but no file will get extracted)